# PHP Constant inside IF

Tags: php, constants

having problems with constants in PHP wondering if someone can explain:

this works

```
const _ROOT = 'd:/aphp/www';

echo "r="._ROOT;
```

as does this:

```
if (true) 
        define('_ROOT','d:/aphp/www');

echo "r="._ROOT;
```

but this gives the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST

```
if (true) 
    const _ROOT = 'd:/aphp/www';

echo "r="._ROOT;
```

I am using php 5.3.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because ..

The `const` keyword must be declared at the top-level scope

From the PHP Docs

> Note: As opposed to defining constants using define(), constants
> defined using the const keyword must be declared at the top-level
> scope because they are defined at compile-time. This means that they
> cannot be declared inside functions, loops or if statements.

[`Source`](https://www.php.net/language.constants.syntax)

Comment: thanks, it was hidden in a "Note" here http://php.net/language.constants.syntax